# I need to Convet Dart Function to Vue js axios.post()

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dart, multipartform-data

this is my dart function to upload a selected image to node server i need to do this using the Vue js.

```
 var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(file.openRead()));
    var length = await file.length();
    var uri = Uri.parse(_url);
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('img', stream, length,
        filename: Path.basename(file.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input id="file-upload" type="file" />
```

and in Vue Methods you create an async function that sends the request.

```js
let file = document.querySelector("#file-upload").files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("binFile", file);

try{
 let res = await axios.post('<enpoint upload url>', formData, {
   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
 });
}
catch(e){
//in case await fails(4xx,5xx error)
}
```

Comment: in the question MultipartRequest has custom object creation.    ``` http.MultipartFile('img', stream, length,  filename: Path.basename(file.path));``` So is this working?

Comment: i have same problem. so need need to create that object custom or [file] object is default going with this format @alexkarpen